# Button animation after click in quiz app (Android)

Tags: android

I have quiz app. When someone click correct answer, then Button should change color for green and after that I want load new question(I have it in ListArray). It's important: App should wait to the end of animation(in this moment all buttons are disabled) and after that load next question.

Could anybody give me a hint how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Handler to post after the animation is done. If your animation is 3 seconds, you'd do it like so.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Runnable codeToRun = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadNewQuestion();
    };
mHandler.postDelayed(codeToRun, 3000); //Runs the runnable on the UI thread after 3 sec
```

Or you can set an animation listener (Handlers are better)

```
Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.my_anim);
Runnable codeToRun = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadNewQuestion();
    }
};
AnimationListener myAnimationListener = new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        runOnUiThread(codeToRun);
    }
};
myAnim.setAnimationListener(myAnimationListener);
button.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is trickier than it sounds.  You need to do the work of manipulating the questions on a thread other than the main (GUI) thread.   Try looking at this tutorial to understand Handler.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#handler